# ID CS6: Matching blacks for printing via POD services?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, color-reproduction, black

I'm an experienced but self-taught InDesign user. I can put a book together for print, but I've got gaps in some basics. Still, everything I've done through POD services so far has printed clean. Now I want to print a book of b&w sketches, working from scans.

Some of the black tones vary from drawing to drawing, some change slightly when scaled to the page. On some pages, I've set drawings into black rectangles in InDesign, but haven't been able to match their tones with any precision.

Is there any magic wand solution that will ensure all black tones in the document will output for PDF/print with uniform values? I'm hoping there's some setting or process that will take all black values in a certain range and bring them into harmony for printing.

Am I hoping for too much?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure you could achieve that at the layout stage. After all, you could still add new drawings later on and not being consistent. On the other hand, you may want to look at PDF prepress tools such as PitStop Pro or Callas PDF ToolBox which both can convert a tone of grey values to pure or rich black.